# Cannot open/save files on El Capitan. Is this a permissions problem?

Tags: ssd, macos, permission

I have some issues with my file system on my MacBook; I am running OS X El Capitan with an SSD.

For instance, if I make a screenshot, save the file on my desktop, and then immediately try to open the file, I cannot do so because I lack permissions to open the file.

However, when looking at the permissions of the file, I can assure that I am the owner of the file and that I have R, W, and X access.

The strange thing is, when I try to open the file again after a couple of minutes, it suddenly works, even though file permissions are still the same as before.

What can be the reason for this? Is it a hard drive issue?